# Parallelograms $OAEB$, $OBFC$, $OCGD$, $ODHA$ are complated from any point $O$ in parallelogram $ABCD$. Show $EFGH$ is a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and $O$ is any point. The parallelograms $OAEB$, $OBFC$, $OCGD$, $ODHA$ are completed,  Prove that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram.

How can this be proved using the concept of congruence of triangles?

I have thought about this a lot and I still can't figure out the proof, someone please help me solve this.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

EDIT 1:

A vector diagram as needed is drawn, labelling the vectors and adding them as per their color named parallels ( g for green, r for red etc.). The unconnected quadrilateral EFGH is a parallelogram.

( However note that internal point $O$ does not lie on straight lines AC or BD which are not diagonals, and these considerations are unnecessary).

Comment: Thank you...but as I mentioned in the question, I needed a more elementary proof involving congruence of triangles and not vectors :)

Comment: Please identify the congruent triangles , that iis why  put in color code.

Comment: I have not done vector algebra so I have no idea of what you mean by "add them as per color code"...can you give a more elementary proof

Comment: Can you identify congruent triangles of same color between parallels ?

Comment: Yes I can but that doesn't help me prove that EFGH is a parallelogram!

Comment: Next Hint is join O to E,F,G and H, and also  lines between E,F,G, H.

Comment: I don't have a problem in drawing the figure or identifying congruent triangles. I have picked up this problem because I am pretty familiar with geometry. What i need is a real hint for solving the question, not starting off with the problem!

Comment: I would use the characterization of parallelograms as having two pairs of parallel edges, each pair having equal length. This picture is misleading because the diagonals of ABCD should be straight lines through $O$.