# High School Mathematics: A problem on parallelograms

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and $O$ is any point. The parallelograms $OAEB$,
> $OBFC$, $OCGD$, $ODHA$ are completed. Show that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram

I did see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958852/gms-oaeb-obfc-ocgd-odha-are-complated-from-any-point-o-in-gm-abcd-show-e) question but it doesn't have the complete answer.

The main problem is to prove the co-linearity of the points $EBF, GCF, HDG$, and $EAH$, which I am unable to figure out. After proving that, the question becomes straight forward.

To prove $\angle EBF=180^\circ$,

$180^\circ - \angle ABC = \angle DCB$ and $\angle CBF = \angle OCB$

If we prove $\angle DCO= \angle ABE$, the question can be solved. Is there any other method to solve this question? Thanks in advance

Comment: In your question, $E$ isn't even defined?

Comment: @AlanChung I believe that E, F, G, H are *defined* to be the points that make the quadrilaterals into parallelograms.

Comment: oh I see what you mean

Comment: You can't prove the colinearity, because they are not colinear necessarily.

Comment: You must show that triangles $EBF\cong GDH$ and $EAH\cong FCG$. Taking into account that pairs of parallel lines form congruent angles.

Comment: The other question does have a mostly complete answer, its just missing the characterization of parallelograms. But its blatant

Answer (score 0):

I can send you the figure uf you give me an address.

Hint: In figure I constructed following points are considered, the intersection of diagonals of ABCD is M.

1- In parallelogram OAEB , vertex E is mirror of O about the midpoint of AB.Also $AE||OB||FC$, so we can construct  parallelogram AECF with diagonals AC and EF which passes point M.

2- In parallelogram ODGC , vertex G is mirror of O about the midpoint of DC.also $ GC||OD||AH$, so we can construct parallelogram AGCH with diagonals AC and HG. The midpoint  of this diagonal is coincident on intersection of diagonals of ABCD, i.e M.

3- In parallelogram ODAH , vertex H is such that $HD||AD||BC$.

4- In parallelogram OBFC , vertex F is such that $OF||BC$, also $FC||OB||AE$.

From 3 and 4 we conclude that OH and OF are co-linear.

In triangles AHE and CGF two sides are equal and parallel i.e $GC(||=)AH$ and $FC(||=)AE$, that is they are equal and their third sides are also parallel, ie, $HE||FG$.So EF can also be the diagonal of a parallelogram as well as it is the diagonal of parallelogram AECF mentioned in 1. That is $EG||HF$ and EFGH is a parallelogram.

Comment: Your diagram is special. According to it $EGFH$ is a parallelogram, but not $EFGH$. You have also said that $EF$ is a diagonal, but in the problem it should be a side.